# Pandoc 2.x renders images' alternative texts in an inaccessible fashion

Tags: image, accessibility, pandoc, figure

Since I upgraded from Pandoc v1.19 to 2.9, decorative images are not exported as expected anymore.

First of all, when generating HTML from `![](test.jpg)`, in v1.19 a `<p class="figure">` structure was wrapped around the image, but now it's only a `<p>`:

```
<p>
  <img src="test.jpg">
</p>
```

This makes it harder to style in line with other images that have an alternative text.

But what's really a problem here: there's no `alt=""` attribute produced anymore! This means that e.g. screen readers will not recognise this as a decorative image anymore.

So let's see what happens to an image with an actual alternative text, e.g. when generating HTML from `![Hello](test.jpg)`:

```
<div class="figure">
  <img src="test.jpg" alt="">
  <p class="caption">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Here we get a `class="figure"` in the surrounding element, but now it's a `<div>` instead of a `<p>` (I don't bother too much about this, but again, it makes it harder to style everything the same).

What again is a big problem though is the fact that the `alt` attribute is now set empty: this prevents screen readers from perceiving them at all, which is horribly wrong! I guess that Pandoc concludes that having alternative text and caption would be redundant, which is correct, and that the caption below would be the right thing to show - which it is not.

The right structure would look something like this:

```
<div class="figure">
  <img src="test.jpg" alt="Hello"><!-- Leave the alternative text on the image -->
  <p class="caption" aria-hidden="true">Hello</p><!-- Hide the redundant visual alternative text from screen readers -->
</div>
```

Any reason why this behaviour would make sense? Can it be changed somehow? Otherwise I will have to fiddle around with some post-processing JavaScript...

Comment: looks like someone who doesn't understand accessibility has updated the library (or the syntax has changed, have you checked that is still the correct method for adding `alt` attributes) . If it is because someone hasn't considered accessibility then I am afraid the simple answer is for you to extend / rewrite / modify the library to return it to the former method. Better yet if you do have to modify the library, why not use an actual `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` element? You would still need an `alt` description on the image though.

Answer (score 1):

The `![](test.jpg)` example is no longer treated as a figure, because pandoc now requires that

1. the image is the only element in a paragraph, and
2. it has a caption.

Wrapping of figures with `<div>` happens when exporting to HTML4. Using the latest pandoc 2.9.2.1 and running `pandoc -t html5` on the input `![Hello](test.jpg)`

```html
<figure>
<img src="test.jpg" alt="" /><figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
</figure>
```

The rationale for emitting an empty `alt` attribute is that screen readers would read the caption twice: first the `alt`, then the `figcaption`. Your suggestion seems much better, please [open an issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues).

If you can't wait for a new release, then use a Lua filter to create figures the way you like:

```lua
function Para (p)
  if #p.content == 1 and p.content[1].t == "Image" then
    local image = p.content[1]
    local figure_content = pandoc.List{}
    figure_content:insert(image)
    figure_content:insert(
      pandoc.RawInline('html', '\n<p class=caption aria-hidden="true">'))
    figure_content:extend(image.caption)
    figure_content:insert(pandoc.RawInline('html', '</p>'))
    local attr = pandoc.Attr("", {"figure"})
    return pandoc.Div({pandoc.Plain(figure_content)}, attr)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why a figure is not treated as a figure anymore when it doesn't have a caption?

Comment: I created an Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6491

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim the change was causes by this issue: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2844